# Making an Xcode behavior for debugging the view hierarchy

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript

I want to be able to run a custom script for Xcode on a `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect runtime `AutoLayout` errors. This is extensible to other debugging scenarios such as threading and  runtime crashes I suppose, as well as `AVPlayer`. Xcode has a `Behaviors` pane accessible via `Xcode->Preferences->Behaviors` for improving developer workflow with custom automations like opening new tabs, navigating to issues and selecting sidepanels.

I have tried to trigger a new Xcode tab on `Debug View Hierarchy` as follows:

[image: GPU Frame Capture behavior]

This works for capturing GPU Frames, but doesn't work for Debugging View Hierarchy. Here's what I mean:

[image: GPU Frame Capture button]

My question is how can I create an Xcode behaviour to trigger on exclusively the `Debug View Hierarchy` event. Note I could set a breakpoint for `Running -> Pauses` but then this blocks every breakpoint and does not differentiate between different *types* of execution interruption.

Adding custom behaviors for different types of breakpoint e.g Exception, Symbolic and Test Failure would also be great. Ideally I want to stay in Xcode, but would be open to tooling with AppleScript too. I tried using AppleScript via the run `Custom Script` option, but couldn't open a new tab with a given name or detect the type of interruption definitively.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: For future reference, I filed a feature request with Apple via Feedback Assistant. They prompted me for details and the issue remains open.